# Stylize scrollbar with two elements only

Tags: jquery, html, css, nicescroll

I'm trying to stylize the scrollbar using NiceScroll Plugin, I'm doing so with css besides the parameters it offers, the thing is that it creates two HTML elements, and the design I have "has" three elements.

here are the parameters I'm using:

```
$('.albums').niceScroll({
    cursorcolor: '#D289A6',
    cursorwidth: '10',
    cursorborder: '',
    cursorborderradius: '12px',
    background: '#fff'
});
```

Here is the image of the scrollbar:

[image]
And here is the jsFiddle I created to reproduce it: http://jsfiddle.net/YKhce/

I'm missing the white "rail", and I donb't want to use :before and :after pseudo-elements because the users will use this mostly in IE.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you could draw it with box-shadow and outline:
http://jsfiddle.net/ScndL/

```
#outter {
    width: 25px;
    height: 400px;
    background:white;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow:inset -1px 0 0 10px #2956a1, 0 0 0 3px #2956a1;
    outline: solid 5px #2956a1;
    outline-offset:-2px
}
```

update to square 
http://jsfiddle.net/ScndL/1/

```
#outter {
    width: 25px;
    height: 400px;
    background:white;
    box-shadow:inset -1px 0 0 10px #2956a1;
}
```

Comment: That's a good step, bit I need the inner white part with rounded corners and the outter blue with no corners.

Comment: oki, so it is even more simple. remove border-radis and outline. See updated jsFiddle

Comment: I don't think I got it, If I remove the border radius the pink part loses it's rounded corners, but what I need is the white part with rounded corners and the blue part without rounded cornes.

Comment: did you have time to check jsfiddle updated (see lower in the answer :) )

Comment: Do you mean this one http://jsfiddle.net/ScndL/1/? Yes, I saw it, but I still do not understand what you mean. :/

Comment: yes , or do i totally misunderstand you ? First one looked similar to your screen, rounded inside, square outside. Second is just square outside and inside. Pinkish button remains rounded in both.

Comment: Maybe, summed up I need this:
Pink part: rounder corners
white part: rounded corners
blue part: NO rounder corners

Comment: Can you send me the link to the jsFiddle where is was rounded inside and square outside? I never saw that part.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ScndL/3 rd & http://jsfiddle.net/ScndL/4 th version gives it some depht

Comment: Thanks for you answers, but I think I might go with a background image better, I think it is a better, more accurate solution.

Comment: for sure, no matter how old is the browser then ;)